# Failing to import class from __init__.py

Tags: python, module, importerror

There is a module called [uszipcode](https://pypi.org/project/uszipcode/#:%7E:text=%60%60uszipcode%60%60%20is%20the,search%20behavior%20as%20you%20wish.). The content of the module directory after installation if that matters:

[image]

The `__init__.py` file contains:

```
from ._version import __version__

__short_description__ = (
    "USA zipcode programmable database, includes "
    "2020 census data and geometry information."
)
__license__ = "MIT"
__author__ = "Sanhe Hu"
__author_email__ = "husanhe@gmail.com"
__maintainer__ = "Sanhe Hu"
__maintainer_email__ = "husanhe@gmail.com"
__github_username__ = "MacHu-GWU"

try:
    from .search import (
        SearchEngine,
        SimpleZipcode, ComprehensiveZipcode, ZipcodeTypeEnum, SORT_BY_DIST,
    )
except ImportError as e:  # pragma: no cover
    print('hey', e)
except: # pragma: no cover
    raise
```

Here's [search.py](https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/uszipcode-project/blob/master/uszipcode/search.py) (I've made no changes to any of the files)

When I run this code in a script:

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
```

I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'SearchEngine' from 'uszipcode' (d:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\__init__.py)`

What is causing this?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce that error. Could you show us the contents of `d:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\search.py`  and let us know what version of Python you're using?

Comment: @fakedad that file is too long but I linked to it on Github. Thanks.

Comment: If you comment out the `try`/`except` blocks in `__init__.py` and then run `import uszipcode.search; print(uszipcode.search.__file__)`, do you get `d:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\search.py` ?

Comment: @fakedad hmmm any attempt to import uszipcode.search leads to `ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less`. I wonder if that is the cause

Comment: That seems plausible. You may need to update `numba`. Also check that your version of Python is not too old. I'm able to use `numba` with `numpy` 1.24.

Comment: @fakedad Thank you. I forgot to mention; my Python is 3.9.12